# C# MVC 5 - How To Get a Table In a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I'm trying to make a HTML table with a checkbox column where this checkbox column is from a ViewModel:

```
public string FirstName ...
public string LastName ...
public bool Checked ...
```

I want to get the `List<ViewModel>` and pass it to the controller, using a Partial View, to verify the checked columns, because I want to delete the checked lines.

If I wanted to get the checked columns in the same controller, I do, but in a different controller, I don't. In my case, this 'Partial View' is a BS Modal.

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but it's still very unclear.  Can you please clarify what you are asking for?  Do you just want to send the checked items to the controller for them to be deleted, and then have the Partial View updated?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a partial rendered through Ajax. You call the action method from a modal using `load` and POST the form data so it removes checked lines. You can call any controller you need from this, all you need is:

```
$('#target').load('@Html.Url("Action", "Controller")');
```

And on submit:

```
$('#targetform').submit(function (e) {
    var data = JSON.stringify($(e.currentTarget).serialize());
    $.post('@Html.Url("Action", "Controller")', data, function (html) {
        $('#target').html(html);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Got it... But what I want is pass the 'table' to 'Post action' of the PartialView, and then I'll treat the table, selecting only the columns with the 'input type check == true'.

Comment: You'll need to a way to identify which rows through the input field. Your controller should be concerned with a list of data it can filter based on the checkboxes